# Анимация в FBX ASCII

Tags: анимация, fbx

Я создаю библиотеку для чтения FBX файлов. Встал вопрос импорта анимации.

Для примера я создал FBX файл со сферой, которая увеличивается в объёме по мере проигрывания анимации. Вот кусок файла с анимацией:

```
       ;Models animation
    ;----------------------------------------------------
    Model: "Model::Sphere01" {
        Version: 1,1
        Channel: "Transform" {
            Channel: "T" {
                Channel: "X" {
                    Default: -1,60565185546875
                    KeyVer: 4005
                    KeyCount: 4
                    Key: -4618615800,-1,60565185546875,U,s,0,0,a,0,333233326673508,0,333233326673508,-1539538600
                                    ,-1,60565185546875,U,s,0,0,a,0,333233326673508,0,333233326673508,0,-1,60565185546875
                                    ,U,s,0,-0,a,0,333233326673508,0,333233326673508,38488465000,-1,60565185546875,U,s
                                    ,0,0,r,0,333233326673508
                    Color: 1,0,0
                }
                Channel: "Y" {
                    Default: 0
                    KeyVer: 4005
                    KeyCount: 4
                    Key: -4618615800,0,U,s,0,0,a,0,333233326673508,0,333233326673508,-1539538600,0,U,s,0,0
                                    ,a,0,333233326673508,0,333233326673508,0,0,U,s,0,-0,a,0,333233326673508,0,333233326673508
                                    ,38488465000,0,U,s,0,0,r,0,333233326673508
                    Color: 0,0,1
                }
                Channel: "Z" {
                    Default: -0,759918212890625
                    KeyVer: 4005
                    KeyCount: 4
                    Key: -4618615800,0,759918212890625,U,s,-0,-0,a,0,333233326673508,0,333233326673508,-1539538600
                                    ,0,759918212890625,U,s,-0,-0,a,0,333233326673508,0,333233326673508,0,0,759918212890625
                                    ,U,s,-0,0,a,0,333233326673508,0,333233326673508,38488465000,0,759918212890625,U,s
                                    ,-0,-0,r,0,333233326673508
                    Color: 0,1,0
                }
                LayerType: 1
            }
            Channel: "R" {
                Channel: "X" {
                    Default: 0
                    KeyVer: 4005
                    KeyCount: 4
                    Key: -4618615800,0,U,s,0,0,a,0,333233326673508,0,333233326673508,-1539538600,0,U,s,0,0
                                    ,a,0,333233326673508,0,333233326673508,0,0,U,s,0,-0,a,0,333233326673508,0,333233326673508
                                    ,38488465000,0,U,s,0,0,r,0,333233326673508
                    Color: 1,0,0
                }
                Channel: "Y" {
                    Default: -0
                    KeyVer: 4005
                    KeyCount: 4
                    Key: -4618615800,0,U,s,0,0,a,0,333233326673508,0,333233326673508,-1539538600,-0,U,s,0,0
                                    ,a,0,333233326673508,0,333233326673508,0,0,U,s,0,-0,a,0,333233326673508,0,333233326673508
                                    ,38488465000,0,U,s,0,0,r,0,333233326673508
                    Color: 0,1,0
                }
                Channel: "Z" {
                    Default: 0
                    KeyVer: 4005
                    KeyCount: 4
                    Key: -4618615800,0,U,s,0,0,a,0,333233326673508,0,333233326673508,-1539538600,0,U,s,0,0
                                    ,a,0,333233326673508,0,333233326673508,0,0,U,s,0,-0,a,0,333233326673508,0,333233326673508
                                    ,38488465000,0,U,s,0,0,r,0,333233326673508
                    Color: 0,0,1
                }
                LayerType: 2
            }
            Channel: "S" {
                Channel: "X" {
                    Default: 1,10262703895569
                    KeyVer: 4005
                    KeyCount: 4
                    Key: -4618615800,1,10262703895569,U,s,0,0,n,-1539538600,1,10262703895569,U,s,0,0,n,0,1,10262703895569
                                    ,U,s,0,-0,n,38488465000,1,80670952796936,U,s,0,0,n
                    Color: 1,0,0
                }
                Channel: "Y" {
                    Default: 1,10262703895569
                    KeyVer: 4005
                    KeyCount: 4
                    Key: -4618615800,1,10262703895569,U,s,0,0,n,-1539538600,1,10262703895569,U,s,0,0,n,0,1,10262703895569
                                    ,U,s,0,-0,n,38488465000,1,80670952796936,U,s,0,0,n
                    Color: 0,1,0
                }
                Channel: "Z" {
                    Default: 1,10262703895569
                    KeyVer: 4005
                    KeyCount: 4
                    Key: -4618615800,1,10262703895569,U,s,0,0,n,-1539538600,1,10262703895569,U,s,0,0,n,0,1,10262703895569
                                    ,U,s,0,-0,n,38488465000,1,80670952796936,U,s,0,0,n
                    Color: 0,0,1
                }
                LayerType: 3
            }
        }
        Channel: "Visibility" {
            Default: 1
            Color: 0,75,0,0
            LayerType: 1
        }
    }
```

Что означают эти ряды чисел?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Долгие поиски в сети ничего не дали, так что пришлось разобраться самому.
К счастью, это оказалось не так сложно:

- Каждый Channel с буквами T, R и S обозначает соответствующее
  преобразование: перемещение (**T**ransformation), вращение
  (**R**otation) и масштабирование (**S**cale).
- Вложенные в них Channel'ы отвечают за координаты - X, Y, Z.
- Теперь самое сложное, над чем мне пришлось попотеть. Лучше разберу это на примере одного ключа:

  ```
  -4618615800,0,759918212890625,U,s
  ```

  Первый элемент (-4618615800) обозначает время. Я не знаю, в какой единице измерения оно сохраняется, однако можно увидеть время всей анимации и сопоставить его с ключами. Это можно сделать, просмотрев часть файла, которую я не включил в вопрос:

  ```
  LocalTime: 61581544000
  ```

  Второй же элемент обозначает значение параметра (перемещения, вращения, масштабирования) на данном кадре.

  Интерполяция здесь отсутствует, так что её придётся выполнять самому.